# tf.confusion_matrix and InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to run `train.py` from, [here](https://github.com/sankit1/cv-tricks.com/tree/master/Tensorflow-tutorials/tutorial-2-image-classifier). It is based on [this tutorial](http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/). I wanted to find the confusion matrix, and added that after the last line in `train.py`:

```
confusionMatrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true_cls,predictions=y_pred_cls)

with session.as_default():
    print confusionMatrix.eval()
```

I'm however getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float and shape [?,128,128,3]
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,128,128,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Why is that? How can I find the confusion matrix?

Thanks.

Comment: the problem is that there is this placeholder `x` which is used in order to compute the value of `y_pred_cls`

Comment: you need to evaluate `y_pred_cls` before computing your `confusionMatrix`

Comment: also, you might need test data to compute confusion matrix

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies. I think the "validation" data would work? Sorry I'm new to TensorFlow. When you mention evaluating "y_pred_cls", does that mean doing something like "y_pred_cls.eval()"? Appreciate if you can kindly elaborate on that.

Comment: I am trying to come up with the best way to get that confusion matrix in this case. In my opinion, it is better if you do it at the end of the `predict.py` file. When I say that you need to evaluate `y_pred_cls` I mean that you need to have the value for `y_pred_cls` but I don't think that `y_pred_cls.eval()` is the best way to go about it. It is better to run the session. Let me formulate a solution. I will post an answer soon

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for your kind support. You know there is the training/validation stages and the testing stage. If I can do the confusion matrix on "training/validation" at the moment that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The tensorflow computation graph needs to compute the values for `y_true_cls` and `y_pred_cls` in order to compute your `confusionMatrix`.

To compute `y_true_cls` and `y_pred_cls`, the graph defined in the code needs the values for `x` and `y_true` placeholders. These values are provided in form of a dictionary when running a session.

After providing these placeholders with values, the tensorflow graph has the requisite input to compute the value of the final `confusionMatrix`.

### Code

I hope that the following code helps.

```python
>>> confusionMatrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true_cls,predictions=y_pred_cls)
>>> 
>>> # fetch a chunk of data
>>> batch_size = 100
>>> x_batch, y_batch, _, cls_batch = data.valid.next_batch(batch_size)
>>> 
>>> # make a dictionary to be fed for placeholders `x` and `y_true`
>>> feed_dict_testing = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_batch}
>>> 
>>> # now evaluate by running the session by feeding placeholders
>>> result=session.run(confusionMatrix, feed_dict=feed_dict_testing)
>>> 
>>> print result
```

### Expected output

If the classifier is working excellently then the output should be a diagonal matrix.

```
                  predicted
                  red  blue
originally red  [[ 15,  0],
originally blue  [  0, 15]]
```

*PS: Right now, I am not in front of a machine with Tensorflow on it. That's why I can't verify it myself. There might be some mistakes with variable names etc.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your solution I get the result as "[[ 15 0]
 [ 15 0]]", while in @PeterSzoldan's answer I get the result as "[[ 15 0]
 [ 15 0]]", is there a reason for that?

Comment: Ideally it should be a diagonal matrix

Comment: I think that in this case, the order of row and column labels is changed when the graph runs. Is it consistent across multiple runs of the code?

Comment: Yes, it is a diagonal matrix. Sorry it seems the format is incorrect in the comment. What I meant to say is that in @PeterSzoldan's solution the results are swapped, that is 0 is in place of 15 and vice versa.

Comment: _Ideally_ it's a diagonal matrix, meaning in the best case, a class X is predicted for an element in class X so the matrix has nonzero elements in its diagonal only. :)

Comment: If the columns are swapped, that means the predictions are swapped for some reason.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan agreed. It means that class `red` is predicted as `blue` and `blue` as `red`.

Comment: @Simplicity, I am not sure why that might be happening. A common problem in such a case can be that either the true labels are inverted somewhere along the computation graph or the predicted labels are inverted.

Comment: @MohsinBukhari not exactly. His network is predicting red-red in one case, and blue-blue in the other, regardless of input or true label. As I said in another comment: Basically your network produced a different prediction for the two different runs, always predicting one class or the other. Supposing you initialized the weights randomly, this is not at all unexpected, and doesn't depend on which code you use. Run each a few times and you will see it will differ for each run, much like a coin toss. :)

Comment: The result was not diagonal. 15 was under 15 in the matrix and 0 under 0. But, yes, I know that would come with training and more data for instance

Answer (score 1):

The error says that your model needs an input `x` for it to run as per line 39 of [the code you reference](https://github.com/sankit1/cv-tricks.com/blob/master/Tensorflow-tutorials/tutorial-2-image-classifier/train.py):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size,img_size,num_channels], name='x')
```

Basically, if you don't give an input, it cannot calculate the predicted values, much less the confusion matrix! You also need the values for `y_true` as per line 42 at the same place:

```
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
```

So do it like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) 
    print( sess.run( confusionMatrix ,
           feed_dict = { x : [some value],
                         y_true: [ some other value ] } ) )
```

[some value] and [some other value] you should probably have, or if not, just generate some random values for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I'm having an "invalid syntax" when I tried adding your code, not sure why. Moreover, for confusion matrix, as per the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix, shouldn't we pass labels and predictions here? Why is "x" then causing the error?

Comment: Edited answer, added missing parenthesis

Comment: if you are using this solution then add this code (`confusionMatrix = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true_cls,predictions=y_pred_cls)`) before the `print( sess.run(...` and after `sess.run(tf.global...`

Comment: Thanks very much. In the tf.confusion_marix doucmentation it shows that we should pass the labels and predictions. Why are you passing "x" in this case? Shouldn't we pass "y_true_cls" and "y_pred_cls"?

Comment: @Simplicity the tensorflow computation graph automatically computes the values of the intermediary variables that it needs to compute the final variable. The input to the computation graph is only `x` and `y_pred`

Comment: In this solution I get the answer as "[[ 0 15]
 [ 0 15]]", while in @MohsinBukhari's solution, I have it as [[ 15 0]
 [ 15 0]]". Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Sorry it seems the format is incorrect in the comment. What I meant to say is that in @MohsinBukhari's solution the results are swapped, that is 0 is in place of 15 and vice versa.

Comment: Basically your network produced a different prediction for the two different runs, always predicting one class or the other. Supposing you initialized the weights randomly, this is not at all unexpected, and doesn't depend on which code you use. Run each a few times and you will see it will differ for each run, much like a coin toss. :)